# How can I write test cases for @Bean method?

Tags: junit, code-coverage, javabeans, testcase, jmock

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate method1() throws Exception { 
     return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbConnection(), databaseName);
}` @Bean
public MongoClient method2() throws Exception {
    uri = uri + "Example String";
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(uri);
    return MongoClients.create(connectionString);
```

}`
how can I write the test cases for the above methods

Answer (score 0):

If it is an object creation class that knows the expected value, you do not need to perform a test. If you must test, you only need to verify that the object is created and initialized properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).